# how to include a file using angular-js at the <head> section

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I want to include a file inside the `<head>` section. 
(the file conatains all the css, and js file that should be included in every page in the site)

It is done easily with PHP, 
I'm trying to do this in angular and it doesn't work.

How can I include a file inside the  section of an html page using angular / javascript only ?

```
<div ng-include="'/Partials/header.html'"></div>
```

This code should work in the  section, but doesn't seems to work in the  section....

Comment: I don't really understand. A typical angularJS application is a **single-page** application. So you just have a single page with a head section. So what's the problem in just inlining the header in that page? Why use an ng-include?

Comment: You could load your common css and js within your first page instead. And then navigate using $routeProvider which would load the page that you want into your view.

Comment: In a SPA there will be no need to do it. but what if it's not SPA ? (I'm new to angular, maybe I'm applying the wrong pattern here....), yet there is an include directive, I wonder if it can't be used on the head as well....

Comment: If it's not an SPA, you should do such includes at server-side, using PHP, JSP, ASP, SSI or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is don't break the page...

That said you can use ngInclude there.

**myhead.txt:**

```
<title>Hello World</title>
```

**markup:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <ng-include src="'myhead.txt'"></ng-include>
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/QnJ4o2mnQuM75qd2l77a?p=preview (view popped out)